# How to get a result with some user generated columns by SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Mysql database, and I have 2 tables which schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sold_records` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `sold_at` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As you see, I have some items and some sold records, I want to get such a result by SQL query:

```
item_name   sold_count_at_today sold_count_at_yestoday ... sold_count_at_today - 30day
item_1                x                   x            ...        x
item_2                x                   x            ...        x
...
item_n                x                   x            ...        x
```

Could anyone please give some suggestions about getting such a result by SQL query?

You may debug it in that [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92f796/1).

Comment: Yikes. Does this need to be done in mysql? Would be very straight forward in SQL Server

Comment: @kbball Yeah, our database is Mysql...

Comment: Suggestion: join the two tables, use aggregate functions and grouping to get the result.

Comment: @marekful So should I use 30 aggregate to get 30 columns? Or is there any more neat way?

Comment: @kbball could you please show me how to achieve that by SQL Server?

Comment: count( item_id ) in sold_records and group by Y-m-d part of sold_at. That will give you a result with days as rows and items as columns.

Comment: The SQL server version would allow you to pivot. I think below is the best mySQL approach.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you would have to do this with a bunch of case functions, like this:

```
SELECT i.name,
CASE WHEN CAST(sold_at AS date) = '2017-10-31' THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END AS '2017-10-31',
CASE WHEN CAST(sold_at AS date) = '2017-11-01' THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END AS '2017-11-01'
...
FROM items i
INNER JOIN sold_records r
ON i.id = r.item_id
```

I tried this on the fiddle you set up. You can check it out here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92f796/19

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.name as item_name,
count(b.sold_at = (DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(current_timestamp), '%e %b %Y'))) as
sold_count_at_today,
count((b.sold_at = (DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(current_timestamp -1), '%e %b %Y')))) as sold_count_at_yesterday,
count((b.sold_at = (DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(current_timestamp- 30), '%e %b %Y')))) as 30_day
from items a, sold_records b
where a.id = b.item_id 
group by a.name;
```

Try this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92f796/23/0 assuming today is current timestamp.